# phpMyAdmin Error On Local Windows Machine

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, http-status-code-404

I have been getting this error message on my Windows 10 machine:

"Not Found

The requested URL /phpMyAdmin was not found on this server."

Apparently,

I finally had enough of my Wampserver. Uninstalled it. And installed Apache, PHP, and MySQL as separate components.

Everything worked fine(phpMyAdmin incuded), Until I created virtual hosts on one of my other drives. I used the usual route, by uncommenting the httpd-vhosts.conf include in the Apache httpd.conf file- Then, added my virtual hosts to the httpd-vhosts.conf file.

I also included this block of code, along with the other virtual hosts:

DocumentRoot "C:\Apache\htdocs"
   ServerName localhost

The phpMyAdmin folder is in the htdocs folder. However, my websites are on another drive. They are working fine, though. Its just the phpMyAdmin pagr that is not working.

However, almost every response seems to base itself on some 'stack' bundle, such as Wamp, or Xammp. I am not using any of these anymore.

Comment: I think, Problem with your mysql connection. Just check the port bindings in your host.

Comment: Okay. Will look into that. Will update on what happens. Thanks.